# How to get biggest element in HashSet of object by field?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the class

```
public class Point {
    public float x, y, z;
}
```

And I've created this hashset:

```
HashSet<Point> H;
```

How can I get the element of `H` with the biggest `z`? It doesn't need necessarily to use Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0) to mimic `MaxBy` functionality (note that you need to check if collection has any elements first):

```cs
var maxByZ = H.Aggregate((point, point1) => point.z > point1.z ? point : point1);
```

When .NET 6 is out it should have built in [`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
int maxZ = H.Max(point => point.Z);
var maxPointByZ = H.Where(point => point.Z == maxZ).FirstOrDefault();
```

This works by first retrieving the largest value of Z in the set:

```
H.Max(point2 => point2.Z) //Returns the largest value of Z in the set
```

And then by doing a simple where statement to get the record where Z is equal to that value. If there are multiple values, it will get the first one, so you may want to sort the enumerable in advance.

Comment: You should move `H.Max(point2 => point2.Z)` out of the `Where` clause otherwise you will have O(n^2) operations here for LINQ to objects.

Comment: Ah, I never knew LINQ would do that. I thought it would evaluate the Max first and keep the value in cache or something since the list cannot change once the operation has started.

Comment: You can test it yourself by calling a function with sideeffects in the `Where` clause (like `Console.WriteLine`). Also why do you expect LINQ to behave as you said? And how you expect this feature to be implemented for `Enumerable`'s  which use `Func`'s not expressions.